# What does the word "out" mean in the sentence "the correlation is very out"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I just bumped into a sentence spoken by a native speaker that went as "I think the correlation is very **out** there."

From the context, I thought he meant the correlation was **low/weak**. Google Translate, however, says that "out" here means **high/strong**, which is exactly the opposite.

What does that suppose to mean? Is that a legit English phrasing, or it's merely an informal/casual expression?

Or he was actually saying it like, "the correlation is very **out there**"? What does "out there" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

They are not saying it is "out", they are saying it is "out there". "Out there" is a set phrase in English. According to the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/out-there), it means "very strange or unusual" or "out of the ordinary". (Note that their entry is for "out-there", turned into a simpler adjective with a hyphen. In most contexts, such as in your example, it will be a phrase without a hyphen.)

In your context, I think you're correct that they mean it's weak. It's not a phrase I'd personally use to describe a correlation. I wonder if it's conflating "out there" to describe *people* who would believe in the correlation being significant, as themselves being outliers due to it being a weak correlation.

Comment: Depending on context (correlation between what?) _out_ can also mean _inaccurate, off the mark_, as in _the measurements were out by several centimetres_.

Comment: @KateBunting your phrase I've heard used, but I haven't heard it used without a qualifier like your "by several centimetres". Is it used without a qualifier in the UK? In the US I think we'd usually use "off" instead (though I don't work in science), and we can use "off" without a qualifier.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your last sentence correctly. (Could you elaborate more?) Due to my understanding, I don't think this is the scenario. He was literally describing two factors, saying that the correlation between A and B is out there. I think "very strange or unusual" and "out of the ordinary" is probably the case here.

Comment: @AsherShang in that case they might mean strong. I'd expect it to mean strong without the "very" but with spoken emphasis on "out". With the "very" there, I have a hard time guessing.

Comment: @AsherShang for the example in my last sentence, when spoken, there'd be an awkward pause between "very" and "out".

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I'm even more confused right now :< In the original conversation, there was a spoken emphasis on "out", with "there" in a very light voice tone. But I do think the context only makes sense when the "correlation" is actually "weak". Maybe he did say "out-there" as "unusual" or "strange", because its meaning is closer to "weak"?

Comment: @AsherShang well, I guess the context is everything. In general I'd be surprised for a person to put so much emphasis on a weak correlation, unless the correlation was for some reason expected to be strong? But yes I guess it either means "out there" as unusual, or "out" meaning "inaccurate" like Kate was saying (if that's actually grammatical; as I said in my comment before, I'm not familiar with it).

Comment: "Out there" could mean that the correlation is strong between two things that you would expect to be uncorrelated (because that would be weird). For example, if there is a strong correlation between Covid death rate and the number of letters in a country's name, that would be an "out there" (meaning "weird or unexpected") correlation.